# How can I make the disabled-popover work on an element that is not a button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

The disabled bootstrap buttons have a disabled popover. I would need this also on an disabled element that is not a button. Is this possible?

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<span style="float:left;pointer-events:none" class="edit" ><a class="btn btn-box-tool edit-tool btn btn-primary disabled" disabled="" >not a button</a></span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled">button</button>
```